# C# milliseconds until next day (from now)?

Tags: c#, events, datetime, time

Can anybody help me about implementing a like a day change event (with only 1 event, function)? I need this only...

Can anybody help me about creating an algorithm?

- I'll make a Logger system that logs all events in a log file like "28-06-2013". I need to make a event system to understand day change and create a new log file.
- I have tried to make a System.Timers.Timer but it isn't good way to do it. I'll make a thread that waits (sleeps) until x seconds. (x = milliseconds until next day)

**EDIT:** I wont a function that checks first date and DateTime.Now! Because I need call this method after every x seconds maybe but I need a answer like a "Thread.Sleep(x);" implementation! Namely **performance is important** for me (I'll use this implementation in a network project)

Comment: Note the current date, then start a timer, and compare dates until something changes.

Comment: Your questions should be about a specific problem you are having, not general requirements you want other people to implement for you. What have you tried? Have you looked into making scheduled tasks rather than having a program run 24/7?

Comment: @dlev It isn't a good way to do it. I'll make a thread and I'll sleep until x seconds...

Comment: @Gray I don't have a problem, I want to learn a simple (quick) method for implement this. I'll make a Logger that logs events. Logger creates log file like "28-06-2013" and next day I must create an other log file..

Comment: `-3 huh? I need help, please be more tolerant!`  Like the close reason says:  "Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist."  This is a "please give me the code" question with no effort shown.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables hmm. Now I should delete this question. Am I right?

Comment: For starters, there are upvoted answers, so no, you can't delete it even if you wanted to.  Ignoring that fact, you shouldn't delete it, but **improve** it like the close reason suggests.

Comment: Do you need to deal with time zone transitions, e.g. daylight saving time?

Comment: @mikez No, I don't need.

Comment: what you are working on windows application or web ??? you have not even write what you have tried!!!

Comment: @Sac that's a windows application.

Comment: Any technique that is based on calculating the time from now until the next date change is destined to fail in the face of unexpected time changes such as Daylight Saving Time and NTP updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime tomorrow = now.AddDays(1).Date;

double durationUntilTomorrow = (tomorrow - now).TotalMilliseconds;
```

> I'll make a Logger system that logs all events in a log file like "28-06-2013". I need to make a event system to understand day change and create a new log file.

Given that your goal is to put this in a logger, it would be cleaner to just handle this in your logging method(s).  If you track the last write time, you could increment the log as soon as the logging method was called in a new date.

The only downside to using this approach would be if a day occurred without a log event at all - in which case you wouldn't create an empty log file for that day (which may be good, but may not be, depending on your needs).

Comment: But that doesn't work. If the time changes unexpectedly (daylight saving, NTP updates, user changes clock), that's going to fail.

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, you are right but I'll run this program in a VPS that is my network server then nobody will not change this. Also I'll add a log file names checker that checks old file name and new file name. If they are same, I'll re-call this function :) (and maybe I can fix your problem)

Comment: @MehmetFatihMarabaoğlu: Even servers get NTP updates. And, depending on the server, might be subject to Daylight Saving Time updates. Both of those are automatic. And, yes, you might be able to "fix" the problem, but you're still making it much more complicated than it needs to be. Why use a thread or a timer when one isn't required?

Comment: @JimMischel Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to save the date every time you write a log message. Then, when you're about to write a log message, just compare the current date to the previous date. If they don't match, start a new log file. No need for a thread or anything . . .

```
private _lastWriteDate = DateTime.MinValue;

public void LogIt(string message)
{
    var nowDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
    if (nowDate != _lastWriteDate)
    {
        // close current log and open a new one
    }
    WriteLog(message);
    _lastWriteDate = nowDate;
}
```

Simple, effective.

Comment: But I think this code will not work well after 2 days. Am I right?

Comment: No, this code should work indefinitely. Why would you think that it stops working after two days?

Comment: Because of DateTime.MinValue?

Comment: `DateTime.MinValue` is just an initial value. If you want, you can make it `DateTime.Now.Date`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
 DateTime tomorrow = now.AddDays(1);
 TimeSpan duration = tomorrow.Date - now;
```

Comment: This will always give a negative number, since "tomorrow" will always be 0 in this case.  (Your "tomorrow" calc is the same as `TimeSpan tomorrow = new TimeSpan(0,0,0);`)

Comment: Hmm, not works. It gives '-700000000' like output.

Comment: If what you are trying to accomplish is rolling over a log on an event if it occurs in the next day then you would probably be better served to simply hold on to the current date and when the next event occurs check datetime.now to see if the date has changed, if it has, start a new log file. no need for timers.

Comment: sry I didn't test the code. erm... updated

Comment: @ReedCopsy when I message.show the result I get 10:58 minutes (approx.) and that is the time to midnight.

Comment: I think this all misses the point. The OP said his goal is to log events in a daily log,. A timer or a sleep is a waste when you can just create the filename of the log from the current date at the time of the event and write the event to that file. No need to know what time it is.

Answer (score 1):

Make a thread or timer that cheks for something like that:

```
private DateTime today;
private void IsNextDay()
{
    if (DateTime.Now.Substract(today.Date.AddDays(1)).TotalMilliseconds <= 0)
    {
        today = DateTime.Now; //Next Date so you can check every day

        //FireCustom-Event or do your work here
    }
}
```

Edit:
Based on your edit. Do you have to hold the file open/or Db connection or something like that? If not you could write each Log-Entry with the actual Date. What I mean is something like this:

```
using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText(#FileNameWithDateGoesHere#))
```

Comment: I think timer is better option...

Comment: I think it isn't a good way to do it because I must call this function after every x seconds. There must be a 1 function to do it like a "Thread.Sleep(x);".